# Pushing values to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, var, let

```
router.get("/api/cart", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    items = [];
    await user.cartProducts.forEach(async (product) => {
      var item = await Item.findById(product._id);
      items.push(item);
      console.log(items);
    });
    console.log(items)
    res.send(items);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});
```

I want to send the data of the all the products selected by the user back in the array.
The first console log shows the array with the products. While, the second shows the empty array.
Moreover, api is working good no issues with it.
Personally, I think issue is with my javascript concepts.

Comment: Are you saying it sends back the items correctly it's just the second console.log isn't showing what you'd expect? So the only issue is the console.log and not anything else?

Comment: Please give more information, as what the error is what result do you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` doesn't work with `.forEach`. You need to use `for` :

```
items = [];

for(let product of user.cartProducts) {
   let item = await Item.findById(product._id);
   items.push(item);
}
console.log(items)
res.send(items);
```

EDIT :

Also, this method is going to kill your database. If you need to fetch 100 products, then you're doing 100 requests to the DB.

You can achieve the same result in one request :

```
const ids = user.cartProducts.map( p => p._id ); // Array of _id

const items = await Item.find({
    _id : {
         $in : ids
    })
    .lean() // Returns simple JSON, faster
```

Comment: can also use `for await of`  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: @grzesiekmq Oh, I had no idea about this syntax, thanks!

Comment: @anuragGupta I edited my answer with a much faster solution.

Answer (score -2):

this will helpful to you to push selected values

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var tmp = [];
  
  $("input[name='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var checked = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      tmp.push(checked);
    }else{
    tmp.splice($.inArray(checked, tmp),1);
    }
  });
 
  $('#button').on('click', function () {
        alert(tmp);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<input name="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<button id="button" type="button">button</button>
```

Comment: This answer is completely off-topic. OP asks a question about NodeJS, and you answer with something front-end using jQuery O_o